# Difference between substring in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

I was checking the PostgreSQL Manual the last days and I have noticed that [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) is explained there with `substring('string' FROM [int] FOR [int])`.

I normally just use `substring('string', [int], [int])` because I learned it that way from MySQL my simple question is now if this two have any differences is the first one maybe the better choice to use in PostgreSQL or does do the same and these are just 2 different kinds of doing the same thing?

Comment: You can use `substr(string, int, int)` instead if you want. I think the `substring(... from ...)` syntax stems from the SQL standard (somethign which MySQL does not really care about)

Comment: Yes, `substring(... from ...)` is the ANSI/ISO SQL way.

Comment: Oke thanks first to both of you so you explained me that `substring(...from...)` is the normal Syntax while the other one was implemented by mysql makes sense to me even I figured out that mysql is a big difference to all other SQL languages and that's mostly not a good thing!
But is there like a speed difference? Or can I just assume that both syntax types just call the same function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUBSTRING(char_exp FROM start_position [FOR length])` syntax is part of [SQL-92 standard](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) and you are encouraged to use it.

This syntax [also works in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring).

Comment: Oke thanks first.
I got that `substring(.... from ....)` is the standard syntax but how does it make a difference or is `substring('String',int,int)` like an alias?

Comment: No difference, it is just two syntaxes for same function.

Comment: The SQL committee love adding words to things, presumably because they think it makes the syntax more human-readable. My favourite is that they then use the same keywords for other purposes, giving the completely nonsensical syntax `SUBSTRING('foo' FROM 'pattern' FOR 'escape-character')`, which also takes [its own special format of regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP).