# Difference between SUBSTR and SUBSTRING

Tags: postgresql

I've noticed that Postgres allows me to use SUBSTR or SUBSTRING. Both produce the same results. Is there a difference in the two?

Comment: `substring()` is defined in the SQL standard if I'm not mistaken (and it allows for regex). `substr()` is Postgres specific (and does not allow regex)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between substring in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48704934/difference-between-substring-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 2):

There are some differences at least in syntax:

```
substring(string [from int] [for int])  
substring(string from pattern)  
substring(string from pattern for escape)
```

and

```
substr(string, from [, count])
```

See details in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html

Comment: The answers given in the already answered question are questionable.